# How to change excel legend order?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a excel graph with two lines using the primary axis and a column using the secondary axis.  The legend currently lists the column first followed by the two lines.  I would like to list the lines first in the legend since the axis they are referring to are on the left side of the graph.  Is there any way I can change the legend order?

Comment: I thought that the legend always list all entries for primary axis first even if the series order is different. maybe try replotting.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, using Excel for Mac with office 365. As soon as I changed the plot on the secondary chart to 'column', the order changes and changing the order in the 'Select data' didn't change anything. The question has been locked so I can't actually provide an answer but I'll add another comment below with the steps I found to fix it.

Comment: 1) Set up chart as you described - line and column chart with column on secondary axis
2) Used "select data" dialogue to change order so column chart is first in the order - this won't change the legend, but just the order in the 'select data' dialogue
3) Change column chart back to line chart (still on secondary axis)
4) Change order back so that new line chart (on 2nd axis) is now second in the order
5) Change new line chart back to column chart type.

When I did this, the column chart stayed second in the order.

Answer (score 6):

Source [How to Change the Order of the Legend in an Excel Chart](http://www.ehow.com/how_6471721_change-order-legend-excel-chart.html)

> 1. Right-click on one of the names listed on your legend.
> 2. Click on the "Select Data" option from the list that appears.
> 3. Click on the entry you want to move in the "Legend Entries (Series)" box.
> 4. Click the "Up" or "Down" arrows in the box to change the position of the legend. Click "OK" when finished to save your changes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I have tried that but it doesn't work.  I think Excel arranges legend titles by chart type before looking at data order.  I can rearrange the order of the two lines, but the column title is always first.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an image of your graph? And an example of the spreadsheet data?

Comment: This doesn't change the order of trendline legends.