# Reverse Legend Order After Reversing Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have set my values to be displayed in reverse order in my axis options

[image]

But the chart's legend hasn't been reversed to match the order of the values

[image]

Which makes it confusing to view.

The [usual solutions](https://superuser.com/a/929080/351470) for this issue don't seem to work because when the chart's series is changed, the legend is reordered with it (but it remains sorted in the standard order).